# List filter and significance of a comma?

Tags: python, list, filter

I'm dealing with lists and matrices in Python, and I can't understand the meaning of a list filter.

```
myList = numpy.random.uniform(size=(m,n))
```

What does `myList[:,6]` actually do?

List filters without the comma are ok for me (e.g. `myList[1:-2], myList[2:]` ...)

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/509377/3001761

Comment: you should read the numpy documentation

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html (note that *"could you ...?"* is much less rude than *"you shall ..."*).

Comment: [Tentative NumPy Tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) should be a good place to start. This is covered in the Basics section of that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a 2-D array.  The comma is separating the two different directions (rows, columns).  Let's try with `m=3`, `n=8`

```
myList = numpy.random.uniform(size=(3,8))
> array([[ 0.36121954,  0.39804469,  0.25707183,  0.22275139,  0.36949532,
     0.39035669,  0.66837628,  0.37150618],
   [ 0.78177628,  0.63565838,  0.0186624 ,  0.89806821,  0.55308878,
     0.23682234,  0.90985795,  0.92696437],
   [ 0.48673502,  0.65489626,  0.49237721,  0.49957257,  0.96692522,
     0.50905997,  0.02131627,  0.92127346]])
```

So it's got 3 rows, each row has 8 entries (ie. 8 columns).

```
myList[:,6]
> array([ 0.66837628,  0.90985795,  0.02131627])
```

gives the 6th column (with counting starting at 0, so the next to last column of the 8 columns).

More generally we can use the slice notation to get rows 0 and 1 and columns 4 and 5, or similar ranges.

```
myList[0:2,4:6]
> array([[ 0.36949532,  0.39035669],
   [ 0.55308878,  0.23682234]])
```

And to push the slice notation even further:

```
myList[0:2,1:6:2]
> array([[ 0.39804469,  0.22275139,  0.39035669],
   [ 0.63565838,  0.89806821,  0.23682234]])
```

gives rows 0 and 1 and then columns 1 up to 6 stepping by 2 (so 1, 3, and 5).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `myList` is not a list but a `numpy` array with `m` rows and `n` columns.

With `myList[:,6]` you just select the column `6`. `:` means that you take all rows.